# Почему не отображается треугольник с текстурой?

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, opengl

Я хочу нарисовать треугольник с текстурой кирпича, но на экране ничего не отображается. Загрузка текстуры из файла проходит успешно. Ошибок компиляции шейдеров нет.

```
#include <iostream>

#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL.h>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include "stb_image.h"

#define WINDOW_WIDTH 640
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 360

using namespace std;

GLuint shaderProgram;

void LoadAndUseShaders()
{
    GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    const char* vsSource =
    R"glsl(
        #version 150 core
        in vec2 position;
        in vec2 texCoord;
        out vec2 TexCoord;
        void main()
        {
            TexCoord = texCoord;
            gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
        }
    )glsl";
    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vsSource, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vs);

    GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    const char* fsSource =
    R"glsl(
        #version 150 core
        in vec2 TexCoord;
        uniform sampler2D image;
        void main()
        {
            gl_FragColor = texture(image, TexCoord);
        }
    )glsl";
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fsSource, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fs);

    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vs);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fs);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
}

int main()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_STENCIL_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL Texturing", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    float vertices[] =
    {
        -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0,
        0.5, -0.5, 1.0, 0.0
    };
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), &vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 4, (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 4, (void*)(sizeof(float) * 2));

    LoadAndUseShaders();

    int width, height, nrChannels;
    unsigned char* pixelData = stbi_load("brick.png", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(texture, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelData);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "image"), 0);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);

    SDL_Delay(5000);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Если строку из фрагментного шейдера `gl_FragColor = texture(image, TexCoord);` заменить на `gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);`, то на экране отобразится тот самый треугольник, но только без текстуры — это доказывает тот факт, что с шейдерами всё в порядке.

Comment: Отсутствует привязка `uniform sampler2D image;` к чему либо

Comment: Я думал, что вызов `glBindTexture` делает привязку. Странно, что в руководстве от LearnOpenGL.com об этом не уточняется. Спасибо, что заметили.

Comment: `glBindTexture` делает привязку, только не uniform. Собственно это же логично. Вот было бы в шейдере 4 текстуры - как при вызове `glBindTexture` можно было бы указать, к чему привязывается?

Comment: @user7860670 я добавил `glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "image"), texture);`, но всё равно треугольник не отображается. Может обязательно создать мип-карту, как в руководстве?

Comment: В `glUniform1i`  вторым параметром 0 передавайте.

Comment: Это тоже не работает.

Comment: ¿И ошибок никаких нет? А лучше обновите код в вопросе, а то сейчас опять выяснятся интересные подробности

Comment: @user7860670 код обновил. Я проверил с помощью glGetError после вызова метода рисования и получил ошибку GL_INVALID_ENUM 0x0500. Вывел с помощью cout значение 1280 (500 по шестнадцатеричному)

Comment: Добавьте активацию текстурного блока перед `glBindTexture` `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0);`

Comment: Всё то же самое.

Comment: Дааа. Как всегда проблема в тривиальных местах `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D...`. Спасибо за помощь.